# Flow Type with Async Await error checking Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, flowtype

I can't figure out why this code isn't passing the flow checker. I simply send an object to the updatePopper function and inside it I make an api call to update the data in the DB, and then I get a response, decode that response, and return that new updated data to the client-side and update the redux-form with the latest data. But flow doesn't like my code. Any ideas would be awesome!

This is the error popping up:
[image]

// Code in my react submit function

```
const newPopper: {data: Popper} = await this.props.updatePopper(data)
```

// Code in my redux action

```
export const updatePopper = (data: Popper) => async (dispatch: DispatchActionDynamic): {data: Popper} => {

  // Make API REQUEST
  const response = await PopperApi.updatePopper(popperData)

  // Decode JSON
  const body: PopperResponse = await response.json()

  // Check for Valid response and error handling
  await statusCheck(response, dispatch)

  // update redux with new data
  dispatch(updatePopper(body))

  // return response
  return body
}
```

Comment: I don't know much about Flow, but I assume it has error messages?

Comment: @ThiagoBarcala I updated the post with an image of the error

Comment: The `updatePopper` function you posted takes two arguments, but you're calling the props method with only one?